# Why @Singleton over @ApplicationScoped in Producers?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, cdi, ejb-3.1

[LoggerProducer.java](https://github.com/AdamBien/lightfish/blob/master/multilight/lightfish/src/main/java/org/lightfish/business/logging/LoggerProducer.java) is a class used to produce Loggers to be injected in CDI beans with:

```
@Inject 
Logger LOG;
```

Full code:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

/**
 * @author rveldpau
 */
@Singleton
public class LoggerProducer {

    private Map<String, Logger> loggers = new HashMap<>();

    @Produces
    public Logger getProducer(InjectionPoint ip) {
        String key = getKeyFromIp(ip);
        if (!loggers.containsKey(key)) {
            loggers.put(key, Logger.getLogger(key));
        }
        return loggers.get(key);
    }

    private String getKeyFromIp(InjectionPoint ip) {
        return ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName();
    }
}
```

**QUESTION**: can `@Singleton` be safely turned into `@ApplicationScoped` ?

I mean, why would anyone want an EJB here ? Are there technical reasons, since no transactions are involved, and (AFAIK) it would be thread-safe anyway ?

<sub>I'm obviously referring to `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`, not to `javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped`.</sub>

Comment: HashMap isn't threadsafe

Comment: @SME_Dev of course, mine error was thinking that `@ApplicationScoped` is, thanks for the comment BTW

Comment: @AndreaLigios can you clarify whether your question is about `javax.ejb.Singleton` or `javax.inject.Singleton`?

Comment: @johnament javax.ejb.Singleton

Comment: imports are super important here.  inject's singleton doesn't have the qualities of EJB's singleton.

Comment: I agree (now), though they're available in the source code linked at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `@Singleton` annotation provides not only transaction but also thread-safety by default. So if you will replace it with `@ApplicationScoped`, you will loose the synchronization. So in order to make it properly you need to do like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoggerProducer {

   private final ConcurrentMap<String, Logger> loggers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

   @Produces
   public Logger getProducer(InjectionPoint ip) {
      String key = getKeyFromIp(ip);
      loggers.putIfAbsent(key, Logger.getLogger(key));
      return loggers.get(key);
   }

   private String getKeyFromIp(InjectionPoint ip) {
     return ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName();
  }
}
```

Also you can make it completely without any scope if you make the map as static

Comment: Crystal clear. I misremembered `@ApplicationScoped` to be thread safe too, which turns out to be wrong. Thinking about it, it's absolutely coherent: all EJBs are thread safe, all CDI beans are not, no exception made for this scope. Thanks for the answer